# .replace() is not working when applied to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a few columns that have numerical data with commas *(eg. the number is stored as '4,200' and hence not being read as a number)* in base file. To able to process the data I need to remove these commas from multiple columns of data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = {'INR': ['4,200','5,000',0,'4,353','6,000',1],
'USD':['4,100','3,000','1,000','4,353','6,000',1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

If I write the following line of code it works:

```
df['INR']=df['INR'].replace(',','').astype(int)
```

But the following line of code doesn't:

```
df[['INR','USD']]=df[['INR','USD']].replace(',','').astype(int)
```

Would be great if someone can help understand why

Comment: Use `df[['INR','USD']].replace(',', '', regex=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when you call `df[['INR','USD']]`, his type is pd.DataFrame.
This type doesn't have ".replace" method. only pd.Series with this call :

```
df['INR'].astype(str).str.replace(",", "").astype(int)
```

Don't forget the `.str.`

For your case, use applymap method like that :

```
df[['INR','USD']] = df[['INR','USD']].applymap(lambda x: int(str(x).replace(",","")))
```

You can have information about applymap here :
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html

Shortcut method by infering types (I prefer no shortcut method to understand what is doing...) :

```
df[['INR','USD']] = df[['INR','USD']].replace(',', '', regex=True)
```